# How to create an Array2d with custom fill in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I want to create an Array2d with custom value, width and height.

I've searched the internet but only found an array that contains numbers instead of strings

For example, I want to make it like this:

```py
fields_width = 5 # Width of the Fields we specified
fields_height = 5 # Height of the Fields we specified

# And this is the result
fields = [["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
          ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A"],
          ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A"],
          ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A"],
          ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]]
```

Then how to code it in Python

Comment: OK. ...and what exactly stops you?

Comment: @PM77-1 What's stopping me?, I'm struggling to implement it into code, So I asked here

Answer (score 0):

You have a list, you want a 2D array. You can use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) for that:

```
import numpy as np

# you need to tell numpy that it is an array of objects, otherwise 
# it uses fixed-size strings limited to the length of the longest
# element
s = np.array([['a','b'],['c','de doo doo doo']], dtype='object')

print(s[0,1]
# 'b'
```

Comment: So I can't customize the width and height?, meaning the array will follow the width and height according to what we want, for example above is 5x5

Comment: @dns51 it creates an array matching the structure of the lists you pass into it, so if you were to pass a list of five lists of five elements it would create a 5x5 array.